# Formatting server side jQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to format the front end look of my jQuery DataTable

I currently have it looking like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ujAl.jpg

I need the repeating items in each row to be remove for example in the first row there are 2 Owner 1's. I only want to display a single Owner 1 in that row.

The other issue is in row 2, Url1 is followed by a comma then Url 2 but i want

```
Url1
Url2
```

In the row, so removing the comma and adding a new line in that col

My data is being collected via server side processing

My current jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

         $('#result').DataTable({
            "serverSide":true,
            "filter": false,
            "orderMulti": false,
            "ajax": "DetailedSearch?handler=ServerSideDataTable",
            "columns":[
                {"data": "location", 
                 "render": function(data,type,row){
                     return row.location;
                 }
                },
                {"data": "contactAndRole", 
                 "render": function(data,type,row){
                     return data.key + " - " + data.value;
                 }},
                {"data": "server", "sortable": "false"},
                {"data": "urls", 
                 "render": function(data,type,row){
                     return row.urls + '<br>';
                 }
                }
            ],
             rowGroup:{
                dataSrc:'appName'
            }
        });

</script>
```

Can i add some html elements? like a br after each url, or can the table be constructed with pure html then passed onto data tables to output?

I've looked into the HTML templates, and standalone documentation on the data tables website but nothing seems to be helpful.

Comment: the render callback can return html .. yes

Comment: i have ```return rows.urls + '<br>'``` and it doesnt apply the html

Comment: Right but those commas are in your string of url values...or are they an array? If array can use `join('<br>')` otherwise replace commas in string with `<br>`

Comment: ```urls: ["url", "url"]          
   0: "url"
   1: "url"``` this is the json object. This is an array correct?

Comment: Yes so try `return row.urls.join('<br/>')`

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commas for the url's array are because of the default way arrays are processed to strings to be printed into the html in the dom

You could `join()` them yourself using a `<br>` separator instead

```
return row.urls.join('<br/>')
```